# MongoDB unable to wait result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I cannot make MongoClient.connect to await for the results before going on.
I am trying to pass db from the server.js, where I connect my mongoclient, to my routes/api.js where I do my post requests. But it does not work, I always get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Here is my routes/api.js:

```
var db = require("../server");

router.post('/video_url', async (req, res) => {
    const cursor = db.collection('movie').findOne({ link: req.body.videoURL }, function (findErr, result) {
        if (findErr) throw findErr;
    console.log(cursor)
});
```

server.js:

```
var db = async function () {
    return await MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, function(err, client) {
        try {
            if(err) throw err;

            db = client.db('sub-project');

            // Start the application after the database connection is ready
            app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`));
            return db;
        }
        catch(ex) {
            console.log(ex)
        }
    });
}

module.exports = db;
```

EDIT:

```
var dbObject = (async function() {
    var connection = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, client) {
            try {
                if (err) throw err;

                db = client.db('sub-project');

                // Start the application after the database connection is ready
                app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`));
                resolve(db);
            } catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex)
                reject(ex);
            }
        });
    });
    return connection;
})();

    console.log("TYPEOF DB IN", typeof(dbObject))
    console.log("TYPEOF DB.COLLECTION IN", typeof(dbObject.collection))
```

The both console.log() are **undefined**... is that normal?

Comment: i would suggest using https://mongoosejs.com/ . so that you don't need to worry about connection.

Comment: I actually wanted first to try pure mongoDB and understand it before going to mongoose, but I have to admit that I might give it up... mongoDB is such a hassle to use. 
Would you recommend me monk as well?

Comment: Even pure mongoclient version works good let me provide a good example to you. here are some good answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370487/node-js-mongodb-driver-async-await-queries

Comment: I have already seen this post, but unfortunately I still can't fix my issue :/

Comment: you have defined db function but you have not called it. you could have Self-invoking function in server.js that might work.

Comment: don't overwrite `db` from within `db` in your server.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for your `server.js`. Your code was not working because your function was not getting called when you are requiring it.

```
var dbObject;
(function() {
  MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, client) {
   try {
    if (err) throw err;

    db = client.db('sub-project');
    // Start the application after the database connection is ready
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`));
   dbObject = db;
   } catch (ex) {
     console.log(ex);
   }
  });
 })();


 setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("TYPEOF DB IN", typeof(dbObject))
   console.log("TYPEOF DB.COLLECTION IN", typeof(dbObject.collection))
 }, 2000);

module.exports = dbObject;
```

Comment: It is not working still the same error: db.collection is not a function.
But it is probably coming from the routes/api.js: I only call "var db = require("../server");"

Comment: after this changes have you restated the server?

Comment: I am using nodemon.

Comment: But, it is like my routes/api.js file does not wait for the server to return the db object...

Comment: even if it doesn't wait.Your app is not going to serve any request as your app only starts after mongo connection.

Comment: Ahah, yes sure it works, but I don't really want to use a settimeout every time I want to access the db :/

Comment: you don't need to as you app will only start once db is connected. setTimeout is to show you that this will work. because connecting db will take some ms. you can use it in routers and it will work for sure.

Comment: Well, I am not sure, because I get this message: "Server listening on port ${PORT}", and then the two console.logs return undefined, so it means that the db connected and that the server started...