# MongoDB.find() and MongoDB.findone() returns null everytime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I have a nodejs server connected to a MongoAtlas db. The nodejs server inserts data just fine into the collection, but whenever I attempt to find data it always ends up returning null. I have one document in a "Users" collection in my test cluster. but even when I query for everything my results(res) turn up null.

```
function isUsernameTaken(userData)
{
    connection.then(() =>{
        const db = client.db("test");
        console.log(db.collection('Users').find({}));

        db.collection('Users').find({username:userData.username}, function(err,res){
            
            console.log(res.length);

            if(err)
            {
                throw err;
            }

            if(res[0])
            {
                return true;
            }else
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
    })
}
```

This code is one of my functions that involve `db.collection.find`, but for all the other functions I have essentially the same query and no luck. Something else I tried were to query the exact document from inside the collection(`id`,`username`,`password`) but once again no luck.

EDIT: res is not null or undefined, res just does not return any documents from my db.

Comment: So, if `res==null`, then `console.log(res.length)` must throw an error, right? What's happening in the console? What's being logged? Also, `return true` and `return false` return to...... nowhere, they're in a callback function. Also also, you can just `return !!res[0]`.

Comment: since res==null the console is not returning an error its returning undefined, which I guess is a bit different completely my bad. So what is being logged whenever I get res.length or res[0] is undefined. This is what returns when I just log result https://pastebin.com/g0DDwxPZ. The return true and return false are returned in an if statement that is brought up when the server receives a "signUp" request from the client. The returns have worked in the past but since switching to MongoDb instead of an array it hasnt been working due to the results. On a final note, no error is logged.

Comment: No, if `res==null`, then `console.log(res.length)` returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`. Guaranteed. Try it in your console. And no, `true` and `false` are _not_ being returned where you think they do. They are inside the callback function, they are returning from this function, NOT from `isUsernameTaken`. `isUsernameTaken` returns absolutely nothing.

Comment: Also you say `results(res) returns null`, but nowhere in your code is `results(res)` written.

Comment: I see what you mean about the return now, I believe I can fix that easily. Also the res is not exactly null, but undefined. I do not get an error because the MongoDB does retrieve a result, but an empty result with no documents. That is my mistake, sorry for the misinformation. I believe in my previous comment I put a pastebin to what ```console.log(db.collection('Users').find({}));``` returns.

Comment: No. `res` is not undefined either. If it was, `console.log(res.length)` would also throw `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. Also guaranteed. A Mongo response is never `undefined`, it's always something. What you are getting is a Mongo _cursor_, meaning, a Promise awaiting to be resolved, that you need to await. See my answer below

Comment: Ive done it again, res[0] comes up undefined along with res.length. What does have a return is just flat out res. So you are right, res does come out with a value it is just that value does not contain any of the docs in my db no matter my query.

Comment: `res[0]` is undefined, yes, absolutely, so is `res.length`. `res` itself is _not_. It is a Mongo Cursor, a pending Promise. This is why `res[0]` is undefined : `res` is simply not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the `async/await` syntax is so much easier to write, read, and deal with than the good old Promise and callback hell :

```
async function isUsernameTaken(userData)
{
    try{
        const res = await db.collection('Users').findOne({ username: userData.username });
        console.log(res);
        return !!res; // Casts truthy/falsy value to boolean. This does in fact return a value from isUsernameTaken().
    } catch(err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

And then you use it this way :

```
const isItTaken = await isUsernameTaken(someUserDataHere);
```

Comment: This constantly returns true because result constantly gives me this https://pastebin.com/w9tZY8n2. I think what is needed is to check if there is any doc in the result at all, which was the whole ```res.length``` business. Either way the problem still persists that MongoDB.find is not returning the document I am requesting. I took a look at the query in that pastebin and it came up ```query: [Object]``` and I am wondering if that is the problem. But i tried just manually checking for "username":"test" and the query was still that.

Comment: Indeed, my bad, apologies. I forgot to add `await` here : `await db.collection('Users')`, answer edited. If we don't await the Promise, of course it comes back unresolved (pending).

Comment: Wow just checked the time, sorry for taking up so much of your time! With the await I still receive a result similar to that of what was logged previously in the pastebins.

Comment: Then I'm really out of options, because that's exactly how it's upposed to be used according to the documentation. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370487/node-js-mongodb-driver-async-await-queries), it's very similar to what we did here. Maybe the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Nvm it finally works now, big THX to all the help. Using findOne helped me out