# Save into a variable the result from an async function

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

How can I save the result of an async function into a variable so I can use it below?
The code looks like this:

```
app.post('/reg', function(request, response){
    
    var user = request.body.username;
    var pass = request.body.password;
    var quest = request.body.question;
    var ans = request.body.answer;
    
    

     MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
        var dbc = db.db("chat");
        dbc.collection("accounts").find({username: `${user}`}).toArray(async (err, result) => {
            console.log(result.length)
            const a = await result.length;
            return a;
        });

        console.log(a);         <--------- here i got the error: a is not defined

        if(a==1){
            response.send("already_exist");
        }
        else{
            response.send("succes");
            obj={username: user, password: pass, question: quest, answer: ans};
            var dbc = db.db("chat");
            dbc.collection("accounts").insertOne(obj);
        }

        db.close();
        // response.send("yep");
    });
});
```

I have tried a lot of options but i cant find anything useful.
The thing that I want to do here is finding if an username already exists in database, if you have another ideas please tell me.

Comment: You should connect to your database when your boot your application and share the connection rather than having to connect on each request. You will still need to export your connection from some module as a singleton. This way your connection will start when you run `npm run whatever` rather than each request.

Answer (score 0):

the variable a is not in scope of the main function, try declaring it outside at main/global level.
Also you're returning the value from the function, just use it.

```
const results = dbc.collection("accounts").find({..
```

Comment: if i do this, the value its undefined:  const result = dbc.collection("accounts").find({username: `${user}`}).toArray(async (err, result) => {
            // console.log(result.length)
            const a = await result.length;
            return a;
        });
        console.log(result);

Comment: As JS is non-blocking, the result is undefined. As your operation happens in steps i.e. find something, then insert..you'll need to wait till the previous step completes. So, the best way would be to use async/await, something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370487/node-js-mongodb-driver-async-await-queries